# Access Denied error within load csv from Google Bucket to BigQuery

Tags: python, database, csv, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I have credentials in json format that allow connect me from Jupyter Notebook to Google Cloud Platform.
I want load data from bucket to big query, but job return error:
{'reason': 'accessDenied',
'message': 'Access Denied:
File gs://test_bucket/Subscription.txt: Access Denied'}

My configuration for job:

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.autodetect = True
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
job_config.null_marker = 'NULL'
job_config.field_delimiter = '\t'
job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
job_config.create_disposition = 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED'
```

I check that my bucket in non public and i give my credentials role such as "Storage Legacy Object Owner", but it isn't working.
Have you advices/tips for my problem??

Comment: Could you provide more details about your Jupyter Notebook environment (vertex AI workbench, local machine, etc) and the permission you have already granted?

Comment: Hi@Ku9feld, please do not share your service account on the public forum.

Comment: @kiranmathew  Hi! Sorry, it was missclick))
I have Jupyter Notebook on my machine and there is line where bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials,...) i mean that one json, that i use for auth in.

Additionaly, my service account (service account xxx@project_name.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) has permession 'Storage Legacy Object Owner'. Same name in json with credentials near key 'client_email'.  
I guess, my connection must be have taken access to bucket, but i see isn't.

Comment: @kiranmathew I didn't refresh credentials-json in my machine after add permession on my service account from it. Сould it be reason for error? Or update is only  on server side?

Comment: Can you try again after granting the `storage admin role`?For more information regarding roles and permissions, you can follow [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#permissions) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-storage-roles).

Comment: @kiranmathew it's start to work, but 50 Kb file from bucket is loading yet 13 minutes... and job isn't done

Comment: Hi @ku9feld, I'm glad to hear your issue has been resolved. However, if you encounter any issues in the future (50 Kb file from bucket is still loading after 13 minutes, etc), please open a new stack thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the  above comment as a solution:

*Can you try again after granting the storage admin role?For more information regarding roles and permissions, you can follow [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#permissions) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-storage-roles).*

The above issue is related to permissions. The issue is resolved after giving the permissions.